# Arrival/departure program

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that displays a timetable for arrival and departure for airplanes and then asks the user to enter a time in C. The program will then find the arrival time that is closest to the time, entered by the user. The problem is that it's not working as intended and hands me a wrong arrival time that is not even near the entered time. I'm very new to C programming, so excuse my messy programming/logic in my code. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int time0, time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6, time7, time8, t, m, i1 
= 1, i2 = 3, i3 =4, i4 =5, i5=6, i6=7, i7=8, i8=9, u1=10, u2=20, u3=30, 
u4=40, u5=50, u6=59, u7=25, u8=45, y1=13, y2=14, y3=15, y4=16, y5=17, y6=18, 
y7=19, y8=20, h1=17, h2=18, h3=19, h4=30, h5=40, h6=40, h7=35, h8=7, g1, g2, 
g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, c, v;

/* The timetable, in which the majority of the variables are used */

printf("Arrival\tDeparture\n");
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i1, u1, y1, h1);
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i2, u2, y2, h2);
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i3, u3, y3, h3);
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i4, u4, y4, h4);
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i5, u5, y5, h5);
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i6, u6, y6, h6);
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i7, u7, y7, h7);
printf("%3.2d:%.2d\t%3.2d:%.2d\n", i8, u8, y8, h8);
printf("Enter your time for departure: ");
scanf("%d:%d", &t, &m);

/*Breaks down the entered time and the times from the timetable in minutes 
since midnight for comparing, later in the program */

time0= 60*t +m;  
time1= 60*i1 +u1;  
time2= 60*i2 +u2;  
time3= 60*i3 +u3;  
time4= 60*i4 +u4;  
time5= 60+i5 +u5;  
time6= 60+i6 +u6;  
time7= 60+i7 +u7;  
time8= 60+i8 +u8;  

/* subtracts the different arrival times from the entered time if the 
arrival times are bigger, else the entered time is subtracted and saves the 
difference in a variable for later use */

if(time0 > time1) {
    g1 = time0 -time1;
} else {
    g1 = time1 -time0;
}  
if(time0 > time2) {
    g2 = time0-time2;
} else {
    g2 = time2 - time0;
}  
if(time0 > time3) {
    g3 = time0- time3;
} else {
    g3 = time3 -time0;
}  
if(time0 > time4) {
    g4 = time0 - time4;
} else {
    g4 = time4 - time0;
}  
if(time0 > time5) {
    g5=time0 -time5;
} else {
    g5= time5 - time0;
}  
if(time0 > time6) {
    g6 = time0-time6;
} else {
    g6 =time6-time0;
}  
if(time0 > time7) {
    g7 = time0-time7;
} else {
    g7 =time7-time0;
}  
if(time0 > time8) {
    g8 = time0-time8;
} else {
    g8 =time8-time0;
}  
/* here, the program should compare all the differences, to check which one 
is the smallest, and then save the smallest hour(s) and minute(s) in the v 
and c variables  */  

v = i1;
c = u1;

if( g2 < g1 )  {
    v = i2;
    c = u2;
}  
if( g3 < g2)  {
    v = i3;
    c = u3;
}  
if( g4 < g3) {
    v = i4;
    c = u4;
}  
if( g5 < g4) {
    v = i5;
    c = u5;
}  
if( g6 < g5) {
    v = i6;
    c = u6;
}  
if( g7 < g6) {
    v = i7;
    c = u7;
}  
if( g8 < g7) {
    v = i8;
    c = u8;
}  
/* The time with the smallest difference to the entered time should be 
printed*/  
printf("The closest time is %d:%d", v, c);
}
```

But it prints the wrong time and i can't find the bug.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: A good first step would be to give your variables meaningful names and to use a `struct` to group associated variables together.

Comment: If you were to create a structure that held information relevant to each flight, e.g. arrival/departure times, airports, etc. whatever information you have -- then you could create an *array of struct* which would allow iterating over your flight data to locate the needed information. Also what do `i, u, y, h, t, m & g` stand for?

Comment: Have you learned about arrays?  Have you learned about structures?  Until you use at least arrays and probably arrays of structures, your code will be unmanageable.  When you find yourself writing `time0` and `time1` and … `time7`, it's wrong.

Comment: I stopped reading the code at `int time0, time1, time2, time3, time4, time5,`. There isn't even a real problem description here, just "*it's not working as intended*". Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not that far in my book. i'm only at chapter 5 in "C programming - a modern approach" at "if" and "switch" statements.

Comment: I said it hands me the wrong time already.

Comment: You need a teacher.  SO is not good at active teaching of 'Computers 101'.  It's much better to learn from.  There are a lot of these 'Arrival/Departure' style questions on SO already.

Comment: @Yaim "the wrong time" is too vague. What is the exact input you're giving it, what is the exact output you're getting, and what did you expect instead? See [mcve].

Comment: I think you need to get familiar with the notion of _array_. My advice: throw this code away, learn about arrays and start over from scratch.

Comment: As i stated earlier, i haven't got to arrays yet

Comment: I agree, that all the variables are very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the logic in this code:

```
v = i1;
c = u2;

if( g2 < g1 )  {
    v = i2;
    c = u2;
}  
if( g3 < g2)  {
    v = i3;
    c = u3;
}  
if( g4 < g3) {
    v = i4;
    c = u4;
}
```

Consider the case `g1 < g3 < g2`. Here you want to select `g1` but what actually happens is?

1) At first you assume `g1` to be the smallest. (**fine**)

2) Then you compare `g2` and `g1` but continue with `g1` as smallest (**fine**)

3) Then you compare `g2` and `g3` and selects `g3`as smallest !! (**error**)

The problem is that you never compare `g3` to `g1` and therefore you select `g3` even though it is actually larger than `g1`. That's not what you want.

What you need is an extra variable holding the current smallest. Like:

```
v = i1;
c = u2;
smallest = g1;

if( g2 < smallest )  {
    v = i2;
    c = u2;
    smallest = g2;
}  
if( g3 < smallest)  {
    v = i3;
    c = u3;
    smallest = g3;
}  
if( g4 < smallest) {
    v = i4;
    c = u4;
    smallest = g4;
}
```

BTW: I'll recommend that you soon learn about arrays as that will simplify your code

Comment: Thanks, you gave me exactly what i needed.